# How to pass variable to constructor methods in events?

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, prototype

In one prototype method I have this code:

```
DragDrop.prototype.startDrag = function() {
// ... other code
  this.mouseMove = this.drag.bind(this);
  ...
```

The .bind is just so I can refer to the object from the function that I call (*this.drag*).

(The event can't be an anonymous function because I need to remove it later else I'll be dragging forever...)

```
...
window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove, false);
}
```

Then this is the aforementioned function that I'm using. This was all working fine in Safari and Chrome but in Firefox event is undefined.

```
DragDrop.prototype.drag = function() {
    console.log(event);
}
```

How is this solved?

As a side note I'm new to constructors and would appreciate knowing if there's another way to do this / without the bind. In an ideal world I'd like to pass more variables to the .drag function too.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I'd like to pass more variables to the .drag function too.*" Shouldn't you just use instance properties?

Comment: Is it a better practice to use instance properties for everything? I just wanted to be able to return values in functions to cut down a bit on these: http://imgur.com/8ShLB4S.

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a bound (binded?!) function?

Comment: Use instance properties for everything that encodes the state of the instance. There are many variables that are not, but I'm not sure what you refer to exactly. Can you be a bit more specific on *what* variables you want to pass around? And no, event handlers can't have return values.

Comment: I feel like your confusion answers enough for me haha, just going about it the wrong way. Thanks a lot for clearing these things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is a global variable in some implementations for legacy reasons (a bad practice started by IE). It should actually be a parameter of the event handler though:

```
DragDrop.prototype.drag = function(event) {
//                                 ^^^^^
    console.log(event);
}
```

Notice that this has nothing to do with `bind`ing the function, your event handler wouldn't have worked unbound either.